# Removing multiple objects from an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

is it possible to remove multiple objects from an `NSMutableArray` by passing it a list or an array of objects you want to remove? Right now I have a deleteAll method that deletes all messages from a Parse server and then removes the messages from the local array.

However as this is asynchronous by the time it finishes deleting and then calls`[myArray removeAllObjects]` there may be a new message received that I don't want to accidentally delete from the array.

So I am thinking of copying the message array before I do the delete operation and when the asynchronous call is complete remove all elements from the message array that are the same as the copy.

Is there a nice way to do it or is my only option to iterate the array and delete if it matches what is in the copy one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the `- (void)removeObjectsInArray:(NSArray *)otherArray` method of `NSMutableArray`

Comment: thanks for this, just what I was looking for. Don't know why I didn't notice it in the docs

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a for loop and delete the objects you want? like so:

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [..... etc....];
NSMutableArray *editArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
editArray = [yourArray copy];

NSMutableArray *itemsToDelete = [....items....];

for (int loop = 0; loop < [yourArray count]; loop++) {

    for (int loop_2 = 0; loop_2 < [editArray count]; loop_2++) {

        if (editArray[loop_2] == yourArray[loop]) {
            [editArray removeObjectAtIndex:loop_2];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could use this yes, but was just looking for a more efficient method. Thanks though